# Android: compile APK with ANT, common libraries from outside the project folder

Tags: java, android, linux, ant, apk

I'm running a web service that allows users to create simple android apps. I'm using ANT to automate the building of the APKs:

1. Create the project folder (eclipse-style)
2. Copy libs (ad sdks) to the libs folder
3. Run ant

The problem is that even if the libs are always the same for all apps, they are pre-dexed for every single app and the build process takes much longer than needed. I understand this is the normal behavior for the setup I have now.

What I'd like to do is keep all the libs in a common folder on the server and tell ant to use those, preventing the pre-dexing process to happen for each app.

I'm not sure what settings to use in ant.properties or build.xml to make this happen.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware that what you want is possible. That being said, I'd switch to Gradle, as it is more likely that you'll be able to pull this off using it than with Ant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lib switch to specify a library
-lib             specifies a path to search for jars and classes. Or put the libs in the standard directories.
Any jars or classes in the directories of the path will be added to Ant's classloader. The order in which jars are added to the classpath is as follows:
*.-lib jars in the order specified by the -lib elements on the command line
*.jars from ${user.home}/.ant/lib (unless -nouserlib is set)
*.jars from ANT_HOME/lib

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a tiny improvement; put your shared libs where you want and than, for each Android project that requires one or more of these libs, just create a **symlink** in the project libs/ directory which point to the desidered lib. You can save space and time, specially if the webserver is used by many users.

To avoid the multiple-dexing stuff, you may try to **build a standalone .dex file of your libs and use it dinamically inside your apps using a ClassLoader**.
You can start from this: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html